# How to prevent double submit in a single event

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

When i click add at first load, it works will in appending text
when I load into another page, and get back in the addform when add button is click it double appends.

```
 <div id="main">

 //start add
     <div id="addform">
       <p></p>
       <button id="add">Add</button>
       <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
     </div>
 //end add

 </div>
```

when i load another page I empty first the variables and even the container.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(document).on('click','#add', function(e){
   $('p').append('Sample text, lot and more...');
   e.preventDefault();
});


 $(document).on('click','#cancel', function(){
    $('#main').empty().append('<div id="viewform">sample text <button    id="addtext">Goto Addform</button></div>);
});

 $(document).on('click','#addtext', function(){
 $('#main').empty().append('<div id="addform"><p></p><button id="add">Add</button><button id="cancel">Cancel</button></div>);
 });

 });
```

here is a similar issue, on my case  jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/CCfL4

Comment: where is addtext element on your markup

Comment: Can you give a scenario where it is happening ...i copied your code its working fine ...may be a fiddle would help here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dbop765y/ its working

Answer (score 0):

Your both event binding has issues,

Your provided code,

```
 $(document).on('click','#cancel', function(){
    $('#main').empty().append('<div id="viewform">sample text <button    id="addtext">Goto Addform</button></div>);
});
```

It is missing closing quote.

```
 $(document).on('click','#cancel', function(){
$('#main').empty().append('<div id="viewform">sample text <button    id="addtext">Goto Addform</button></div>);
 });
```

Same goes for ,

```
$(document).on('click','#addtext', function(){
 $('#main').empty().append('<div id="addform"><p></p><button id="add">Add</button><button id="cancel">Cancel</button></div>);
 });
```

It should be,

```
$(document).on('click','#addtext', function(){
     $('#main').empty().append('<div id="addform"><p></p><button id="add">Add</button><button id="cancel">Cancel</button></div>');
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but still got this issue.

Comment: Is there any function that helps prevents duplicate submission, i used e.preventDefault();

Comment: i have found this sample, and my problem is very similar unto this http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/CCfL4/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for this **$('#add').off('click');**

```
$(document).on('click','#cancel', function()
{

$('#add').off('click');

$('#main').empty().append('<div id="viewform">sample text <button    id="addtext">Goto Addform</button></div>);

});
```

Comment: This should not be an ideal solution though

Comment: but it works, and it does not double submit or double the action, like this http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/CCfL4/